# Xtext grammar rule composite

Tags: java, grammar, xtext, ebnf

Whats the difference between the following two rules?

This first implementation is working as expected:

```
Lane:
    '{' actions+=Element* '}';
```

So I can leave it empty or add any number of Elements.

Whereas the second one throws an exception:

```
Lane:
    '{' (actions+=Element+)? '}';
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Generated EMF Model incomplete: Could not serialize EObject via backtracking.
Constraint: null actions+=Element null
Values: actions(2)
Semantic Object: ....->Lane
Context: Lane
```

Where has the multiplicity of Element in **Constraint** gone?

```
Constraint: null actions+=Element null
```

Comment: This is a bug in Xtext where (a+)? will override the plus by a ? cardinality.